# Passing a function with parameters as a parameter, but which takes the parameter of the invoking function?

Tags: javascript, function

How to make this example work?

The idea is to pass as a parameter two functions, which receive internal parameters of the function that receives them as parameter.

```
function x(a, b, c){
    console.log(a + b + c);
}

function y(a, b, c){
    console.log(a + b + c);
}

function root(param, fn1, fn2){
    var a = a;
    var b = b;
    var c = c

    fn1(a,b,c);
    fn2(a,b,c);
}

root("pm", x(), y());
```

Comment: Where are `a`, `b`, `c` supposed to come from in `root`? What is the purpose of `param`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass values of a,b,c as an array and along with them pass function x and y as parameter to your function

```js
function x(a, b, c){
    console.log(a + b + c);
}

function y(a, b, c){
    console.log(a + b + c);
}

function root(param, fn1, fn2){
    var a = param[0];
    var b = param[1];
    var c = param[2];

    fn1(a,b,c);
    fn2(a,b,c);
}
root([1,2,3],x,y);
```

Comment: Code without explanation is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I would define it as:

```
function dual(fn1, fn2, ...params) { // a rest parameter
  fn1(...params); // spread arguments
  fn2(...params);
}
```

So one can do:

```
dual(x, y, 1, 2, 3); // pass function references, not function results
```

---

Just for fun: You could actually do this with an unlimited amount of functions:

```
const combine = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.forEach(fn => fn(...args));

combine(x, x, z, z, z)(1, 2, 3)
```